# Compiling PHP 7 with mssql support

Tags: php, compile, ms-sql

So I'm trying to switch to PHP 7. Unfortunately I'm in need to connect to an MSSQL Server so I'll need the dblib driver for pdo. With PHP5 you could ust the php5-sybase Package.

So I tried to do it manually following  [this "Guide"](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/php.htm). freetds compiled as aspected but PHP said `WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-sybase`

On an other Website i found simply adding --with-mssql should work, but also failed.

Anyone having any hints or solutions for me?

Comment: I guess you should be glad such a 'hack' exists at all for Linux (I'm talking about the vendor-unsupported FreeTDS as a way to connect to MSSQL), and not push it to its limits (PHP 7 is brand new, FreeTDS is old). If you wait enough or ask the FreeTDS guys nicely, they might be able to update their stuff to cope with PHP 7, though.

Comment: Which OS are you trying this on? OSX? FreeBSD? Some Linux? Windows with cygwin? ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned php5-sybase, I'm guessing you are using Debian or something Debian-based.  Debian 9 (Stretch) and Ubuntu 16.04 currently have php7.0-sybase packages.  If you need it on anything older, instead of compiling it yourself, you should consider asking for it to be added to backports.

- http://backports.debian.org/
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports